# Zipping vectors of the same type results different types within map closure

Tags: vector, rust

**Background**

Given an enum variant type (non-copyable):

```
enum AstNode {
  Op(Func, Box<AstNode>, Box<AstNode>),
  Val(f64),
  // others...
}
```

Attempting to run an operation over two such vectors:

```
fn apply_func_iterative(func: Func, lhs: Vec<AstNode>, rhs: Vec<AstNode>) -> Vec<AstNode> {
    lhs.iter().zip(rhs).map(|(&l,r)| apply_func(func,l,r)).collect()  // l and r are declared differently!
}

fn apply_func(func: Func, lhs: AstNode, rhs: AstNode) -> AstNode {
    // magic happens here!
}
```

Within the closure, the `lhs` elements assume type `l: &AstNode` whereas the zipped `rhs` elements take type `l: AstNode`. (Note the different declarations in the closure tuple).

**Questions**

Why is this the case?

Is there a way to iterate elements of a vector by value instead of by reference?
It would seem this is possible from the observed behavior of the zipped elements.

(In this example, this difference results in a slight oddity in syntax declaration, but in practice, I have hit up against the borrow-checker when passing the reference variable into a function)

*Disclaimer: I am fairly new to Rust*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`Iterator::zip`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.zip) method isn't doing anything special, it is simply combining both iterators. You're finding that `lhs.iter()` yields an `Iterator<&AstNode>` while `rhs` yields an `Iterator<AstNode>` (`&` vs non-`&`).

> Is there a way to iterate elements of a vector by value instead of by reference? It would seem this is possible from the observed behavior of the zipped elements.

Yes, there is a way to control this behavior. The key is to notice that `zip()`'s argument `rhs` must implement the `IntoIterator` trait. Interally, `zip()` will call `rhs.into_iter()` to get an iterator from it. The conventional behavior is that [`.iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.iter) only *borrows* the source and therefore can only provide references to its values. While [`.into_iter()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.IntoIterator.html#tymethod.into_iter) *consumes* or *"takes ownership of"* the source and can yield owned values.

Combining those, you can do `lhs.into_iter().zip(rhs)` to get an iterator over values `(AstNode, AstNode)` or use `lhs.iter().zip(rhs.iter())` to get an iterator over references `(&AstNode, &AstNode)`.

Comment: You can also pass a reference to rhs, eg. `lhs.iter().zip(&rhs)`, due to the blanket implementation of `IntoIterator` for `&'a [T]` that returns an iterator over `&T`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight on `iter()` vs `into_iter()` - makes total sense after reading up on the matter; and +1 for giving the reverse example of zipping both via reference as well.